# Temporarily save image, then upload later when internet is available

Tags: android, image, image-uploading

I have code to upload pictures to the server and it works okay. 
However, when there is no internet, i would like the picture to be saved temporarily in the Imageview then uploaded automatically when internet becomes available (Pretty like what i see in Whatsapp). How is this implemented in Android?

Comment: Where is the picture? Where does it come from? Please start at the beginning. Put all in your post.

Comment: the picture is from the phone's gallery to be loaded first to the imageview in an activity then uploaded to a remote webserver

Comment: If it comes from the gallery then why would you save them again? Just remember the path will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by the following way

- Store your all `image` in a directory. You can use  `context.getFilesDir()`(*internal files directory of projects*).
- Add a [BroadcastReceiver](https://codeunplug.com/check-internet-connection-status-using-broadcast-receiver-in-android/) to listen to Internet Connection.
- when internet is available, get the file list from files directory and upload each file and delete it after upload completed. [to get file list do like `context.getFilesDir().listFiles()`]

Comment: thank you for the principle. Let me try to work it out